# Overwrite property in one properties file during mvn integration-test run phase

Tags: java, maven, parameters, properties-file

I have a `test.properties` file in one of my maven module which is a small project for ui and api testing.

This test.properties file includes a variable `webdriver.url=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub`

When I use the `mvn integration-test -Dwebdriver.url=http://remotehost:4444/wd/hub` as an input parameter to override the original value it has not happened.

Can you help me with how can I do it? I google it but I haven't found anything about that issue.

I appreciate so much your help regarding this topic!

Comment: The answer depends on how you get values from properties file.

Comment: I use the  java.util.Properties and uses the getProperty as well.
`ConfigLoader(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }`

And I just use:
`config.getProperty("webdriver.url", "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub")`